# Splitting a polygon (height mesh) in ArchiCad

Tags: architecture, cad

I have received a DWG with contour lines for a terrain. Unfortunately, two contour lines intersect and is regarded as a closed polygon by ArchiCad. That means that when I now want to change the mesh point height of one of these height linse (selecting a point and clicking "Apply to All"), it selects and changes both contour lines ... This results in me having to go through each and every point in the two contour lines and elevate each point manually. Quite a painful task as I am dealing with approx 800 points in each!

**Is there any way in ArchiCad to split one contour line into two?**

Essentially we are just talking about splitting up a polygon.

Comment: I doubt if this question belongs here or not....

Comment: why not? it is software related.

Comment: May be. I'm sorry.

Comment: height lines are called contour lines in English.